# Does load runner script simulate browser cache from indexedDB?

Tags: loadrunner

In my application , I have multiple polling requests which are served from database for the 1st time and data is stored in browser cache under indexedDB.
Hence for subsequent requests, it gets served from browser cache unless there is some change in server side DB. 
Now when I execute load runner script with enabling browser cache, still the polling requests are hitting to server.As a result call is going to database and application is getting overloaded.

Any idea how I can handle such polling requests so that these should be served from indexed.DB browser cache ??

Answer (score 1):

LoadRunner respects cache control headers.   It would appear that you are using a cache control mechanism which is independent of web cache headers

> Hence for subsequent requests, it gets served from browser cache
>   unless there is some change in server side DB

You would need to implement the same logic in the script as you find in your JavaScript code to determine whether a user needs to issue a query for updated data for a change in the database.   Alternate paths:  Move up the stack to a full browser which then runs the appropriate code for database change cross checks: TruClient, GUI Virtual User, Citrix, RDP